# Programmatically draw new layers to view after view is drawn with swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UISlider` that I need to draw on top of on at arbitrary points along the slider.

I *can* draw the tick marks in `viewDidLoad`, but since I can't yet get the correct bounds of the `UISlider` at this point they are drawn in the wrong places. If I draw them in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I do get the correct bounds, but the tick marks don't get displayed.

I'm trying to draw these marks as follows:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    writeTickMarks()
}
func writeTickMarks(){
    // create a vertical line
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: calculatedXValue, y: calculatedYValue))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: calculatedXValue, y: calculatedYValue + 5))

    // draw the vertical line in blue with a thickness of 2
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.opacity = 0.5
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2

    // add the shape to the slider's view
    self.slider.superview?.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

I've tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` and `layoutIfNeeded` on `self.view` as well as `self.slider.superview` immediately following the call to `writeTickMarks`, but these calls don't seem to have any affect. :-/

**How can I programmatically draw these new layers to my `UISlider`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should work as it is (and without the setNeedsDisplay/layoutIfNeeded calls). Check to make sure you aren't just drawing things off the screen. I've done something similar myself where my calculated y values were putting my points 900px below the bottom edge of the screen.

Comment: Wow. This was my problem exactly. My tick marks were being drawn at the correct y positions in my `viewDidLoad` version of the code, so I just didn't think this could be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer** - I can't answer why the ticks aren't displayed at all when you call your method from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, that's pretty odd. But...

I have had numerous headaches with the same concept - The view controller lifecycle and when it actually understands the view's true geometry. The trouble with `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is that it can often get called multiple times when a UI loads, and that can cause CALayers to be added multiple times.

I also have a `CAShapeLayer` which I use with a `UIBezierPath`. I have a hacky solution that works for me.

1. I do call the `CAShapeLayer` init method in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (equivalent to your `writeTickMarks()` method).
2. I made my `CAShapeLayer` a class-level property, and check whether it's non-nil on every method call:

   ```
   if self.shapeLayer != nil {
       self.shapeLayer!.removeFromSuperView()
       self.shapeLayer = nil
   }
   ```

   I remove and de-allocate it if it is non-nil to avoid it being added on every invocation of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

It's not very efficient, but gets around the multiple calls of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and the unknown geometry in `viewDidLoad`.